# Why am i being asked for my NVMe 1 Password?

Tags: nvme

I am using my work laptop which I got today. When I arrived home to turn it on I was presented with a screen asking me for my NVMe 1 password. I'm not sure how or why this has happened, the only reason I can think of is that I pressed some keys by accident.

Is there away I can just turn on the computer normally? every time I turn the laptop on this screen appears.

> System Security: NVMe 1 Password Required.

Comment: So basically this is the first time you turned it on? Check your employment documents. If the password isn’t there, contact your IT department.

Comment: It appears they installed encryption - call and ask.

Comment: No it was working fine earlier but when I got home and turned it on this message came up? I will ask IT tomorrow. Thank you.